# Android BottomSheet: How can I know if user is dragging up or down the bottomsheet?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, material-components-android, material-components

I have an app with bottomsheet opened upto 90% of the screen height. How can I know if the user is dragging up/down the bottomsheet. I read we can use onSlide() but the offset values are NaN and sometimes outright weird, so it seems kinda unreliable. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

bottomsheet documention doens't work but i think i figured it out to clear up the documentation read:

Hidden state is -1.0, collapsed state is 0.0 and expanded state is 1.0.

for me i see it only going from 1 to 0, and 0 to 1. That is because i did not have a hidden state, my sheeet was always to be shown at  a peekheight. So as an example, if you have a sheet that will never been hidden you can try this:

just keep a property variable called oldOffSet and then do this:

```
behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    var oldOffSet = 0f
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
    
        val inRangeExpanding = oldOffSet < slideOffset
        val inRangeCollapsing = oldOffSet > slideOffset
        oldOffSet = slideOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to also update the oldOffset: `oldOffSet = slideOffset`

Comment: After I added it. It was not there prior to that edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can **add** a `BottomSheetCallback` to know the status and the direction.

Something like:

```
    BottomSheetBehavior<...> bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout);

    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

      @Override public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING){
            // Dragging state
        }    
      }

      @Override public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        // The new offset of this bottom sheet within [-1,1] range. 
        // Offset increasesas this bottom sheet is moving upward. 
        // From 0 to 1 the sheet is between collapsed and expanded states and 
        // From -1 to 0 it is between hidden and collapsed states.
      }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this way like if STATE_DRAGGING, I set the result to STATE_HIDDEN. But, If I keep my finger on the screen while dragging, Bottomsheet starts to shake up and down.How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> In bottomsheet we can access it's behaviour using BottomSheetBehavior,
>   get all states in onStateChanged().

```
final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
```

> BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
>
> BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED

Answer (score 0):

> Use bottomsheet behavior

```
private BottomSheetBehavior sheetBehavior;
private LinearLayout bottom_sheet;
bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);
// click event for show-dismiss bottom sheet
btn_bottom_sheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        btn_bottom_sheet.setText("Close sheet");
    } else {
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        btn_bottom_sheet.setText("Expand sheet");
    }
}
});
// callback for do something
sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
@Override
public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int newState) {
    switch (newState) {
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
            btn_bottom_sheet.setText("Close Sheet");
        }
        break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
            btn_bottom_sheet.setText("Expand Sheet");
        }
        break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
            break;
        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

}
});
```